# How to explode the column value without duplicating the other columns values in panda dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have df like this:

```
id       ColumnA           ColumnB           ColumnC
1        Audi_BMW_VW       BMW_Audi             VW
2          VW                 Audi            Audi_BMW_VW
```

I want to explode the columns based on explode when _ appear. For example for "Column A" like this

```
df['Column A'].str.split('_')).explode('Column A')
```

but when i use similar query for column B then it repeats the values of column A, but i really want that only ID should duplicate. **The desired output would be something like this:**

```
id       ColumnA           ColumnB           ColumnC
1        Audi                BMW             VW
1         BMW                Audi
1         VW                  
2         VW                 Audi            Audi
2                                            BMW
2                                            VW
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lots of reshaping. The key point is to stack then call `Series.str.split` on a single Series with the `id` as the Index.

```
(df.set_index('id')             # keep 'id' bound to cells in the row 
   .stack()                     # to a single Series
   .str.split('_', expand=True) # split into separate cells on '_'
   .unstack(-1).stack(0)        # original column labels back to columns
   .reset_index(-1, drop=True)  # remove split number label
)
```

---

```
   ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC
id                        
1     Audi     BMW      VW
1      BMW    Audi    None
1       VW    None    None
2       VW    Audi    Audi
2     None    None     BMW
2     None    None      VW
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any possibility to not get double index?

Comment: @s_khan92 if you remove the last line `.reset_index(-1, drop=True)` you'll have a MultiIndex that could be useful. Otherwise you can just tac on yet another `.reset_index()` which will move `'id'` into the columns and give you a default RangeIndex

Answer (score 4):

#### `zip_longest`

Very similar to a recent `explode` answer

```
from itertools import zip_longest

data = [
    (i, *tup)
    for i, *other in df.itertuples(index=False)
    for tup in zip_longest(*[x.split('_') for x in other])
]

pd.DataFrame(data, columns=df.columns)

   id ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC
0   1    Audi     BMW      VW
1   1     BMW    Audi    None
2   1      VW    None    None
3   2      VW    Audi    Audi
4   2    None    None     BMW
5   2    None    None      VW
```

Comment: Thanks. I never used this before. But when i try your query i am getting `AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'str'` i even changed `x.str` but still same error

Comment: I'm taking a guess that some of the initial values are `np.nan`.  Try  replacing `df.itertuples` with `df.fillna('').itertuples`

Answer (score 2):

IIUC with `melt` and `join` after `str.split`, I am not change the column name , since the name here is no related to the original df.

```
s=df.melt('id')
s=s.join(s.value.str.split('_',expand=True))
s
Out[265]: 
   id variable        value     0     1     2
0   1  ColumnA  Audi_BMW_VW  Audi   BMW    VW
1   2  ColumnA           VW    VW  None  None
2   1  ColumnB     BMW_Audi   BMW  Audi  None
3   2  ColumnB         Audi  Audi  None  None
4   1  ColumnC           VW    VW  None  None
5   2  ColumnC  Audi_BMW_VW  Audi   BMW    VW
```